# Перегрузка операторов

Tags: c++

Как определить возвращаемое значение при перегрузке операторов ? В каком случае следует вернуть ссылку на объект, а в каком его побитовую копию ?

update:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SomeClass {
    int value;
public:
    SomeClass(int value) {
        this->value = value;
    }   

    SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass &rhs) {
        value = rhs.value;

        return *this;
    }

    SomeClass operator+(const SomeClass &rhs) {
        value += rhs.value;

        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SomeClass a(1), b(2);

    a = a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вопрос слишком абстрактен на мой взгляд, вы бы пример привели в котором сомневаетесь касательно возвращаемого значения

Comment: @ampawd добавил пример

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Операторы бывают двух типов: операторы *c побочными эффектами*, которые модифицируют один из своих операндов (инкремент/декремент, простое присваивание, составные присваивания типа `+=` и т.п.), и операторы *без побочных эффектов*, которые не модифицируют своих операндов, а возвращают результат в новом объекте.

Вот тут-то обычно и проходит "водораздел" по типу возвращаемого значения.

Первые традиционно возвращают *ссылку* на свой операнд, а вторые - самостоятельный *временный объект*. (О какой "побитовой копии" вы говорите - не ясно. Резльтат оператора обычно содержит *новое* значение, поэтому не ясно, как он может быть "копией" чего-то.)

В вашем примере оператор присвивания реализован как раз правильно, а вот бинарный оператор сложения реализован до ужаса криво.

Ваш бинарный оператор сложения модифицирует свой левый операнд. Где это видано? Это странное и неожиданное поведение для бинарного оператора сложения.

Правильная реализация могла бы выглядеть так

```
SomeClass operator +(const SomeClass &rhs) const {
    int new_value = value + rhs.value;
    return new_value; // <- Используется неявная конверсия `int` к `SomeClass`
}
```

Оба операнда сохраняют свои исходные значения, и возврат результата, разумеется, делается по значению.

А вот если бы вы хотели перегрузить оператор составного присваивания `+=`, то это бы выглядело так

```
SomeClass &operator +=(const SomeClass &rhs) {
    value += rhs.value;
    return *this;
}
```

т.е. именно так, как вы написали, но уже с возвратом по ссылке.

Отдельно стоит добавить, что, во-первых, такие "симметричные" по отношению к своим аргументам операторы, как бинарные `+`, `-`, `*` и т.д. рекомендуется перегружать самостоятельной функцией, а не функцией-членом (например, friend-функцией). Во-вторых, если вы перегружаете и бинарные операторы, и соответствующие составные присваивания, то распространенной идиомой является реализация первых через вторые

```
class SomeClass {

  SomeClass& operator +=(const SomeClass &rhs) {
    value += rhs.value;
    return *this;
  }

  friend SomeClass operator +(SomeClass lhs, const SomeClass &rhs) {
    // Обратите внимание, что `lhs` передается по значению
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  ...
};
```

---

"Симметричные" операторы лучше задавать самостоятельной функцией, а не функцией-членом для того, чтобы такие операторы вели себя "симметрично" по отношению к неявным приведениям типов аргументов.

Например, если задать бинарный оператор `+` так, как показано в моем первом примере, т.е. функцией-членом, то будет наблюдаться следующая неприятная асимметрия

```
SomeClass a(1), b(2);

a = b + 1; // <- OK
a = 1 + b; // <- Ошибка: нет такого оператора `+`
```

т.е. такой оператор не будет рассматриваться в качестве кандидата в выражении `1 + b`. Функции-члены берутся на рассмотрение только из левого операнда. А в случае `1 + b` левым операндом является `1`, у которой никаких функций-членов нет вообще.

Но как только вы сделаете свой бинарный `+` самостоятельной функцией, он будет симметричным образом применим в обоих вариантах.

Comment: Если не трудно, проясните пожалуйста, почему "симметричные" операторы лучше отдельной функцией задавать, а не членом.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian: Добавил в ответ.

Comment: почему у вас во `friend` версии оператора `+` левый операнд модифицируется через `+=` ??? сами же это относите к плохой практике - тоесть он должен возвращать результат не модифицируя операнды вообще! и это было бы правильнее `+=` перегрузить через `+` и оператор присваивания `=` (хотя наверное лучше было вобще оставить `+=` без изменения ), а не наоборот

Comment: @ampawd: Это моя ошибка. Спасибо, что заметили. В моем исходном варианте применение `+=` к `lhs` даже не скомпилировалось бы из-за константности `lhs`. В рамках такой реализации, левый операнд бинарного `+` должен передаваться по значению и без `const`. Исправил.

Comment: @AnT я не про константность, а про то, что `friend` версия оператора `+` вас изменяет левый операнд, почему ? вы же назвали это плохой практикой, он должен возвращать результат не модифицируя ни один из операндов `lhs` `rhs`

Comment: @ampawd: Что же касается попытки реализации "наоборот": `+=` через `+`, то это в общем случае приводило бы к введению в реализацию `+=` совершенно не нужного промежуточного временного объекта, созданного `+`. Оператор `+=` обычно прекрасно реализуется без каких-либо временных объектов. Именно поэтому идиоматический подход - именно реализация `+` через `+=`. Тема раскрыта и в "C++ Primer" и не раз обсуждалась на SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071167/why-is-it-more-efficient-to-define-operator-to-call-operator-rather-than-the)

Comment: @ampawd: Еще раз: код был ошибочен. Я его уже исправил. Теперь левый операнд передается *по значению* (и без `const`). Так как операнд передается *по значению*, в вызывающем коде соответствующий аргумент изменяться *не будет*. Тут нет той "плохой практики", о которой я говорил.

Comment: @AnT а, вижу всё ок

Answer (score 0):

Не ясно для чего этот класс, но в нём есть несколько недостатков. Во-первых, хоть и было бы бессмысленным в вашем примере, но старайтесь всегда принимать во внимание [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) - тоесть кроме перегрузки оператора `=` также определите конструктор копии и деструктор.

Во-вторвых используйте списки инициализации, вместо инициализации в теле конструктора:

```
SomeClass(int value): value(value)
{}
```

А возвращать здесь можете и по ссылке здесь, зачем лишний раз копировать объект ?

```
SomeClass& operator + (const SomeClass &rhs) {
  value += rhs.value;    
  return *this;
}
```

*p.s.* да и вобще, мой вам совет, реализуйте например класс `String`, или класс для работы с матрицами - тогда подобные вопроса по немногу начнут отпадать

Comment: @ampawd: Вы фактически помогаете автору реализовать оператор `+`, который на самом деле ведет себя как оператор `+=`. Это весьма порочная практика.

Comment: @AnT вовсе нет, этот класс не понятно для чего вобще, следовательно принципиальной разницы нет в перегрузке оператора, нуда он неправильно перегружает `+`, я не заметил этого, но суть не в этом, а в том, чтобы автор научился грамотно писать классы применяя более жизненные примеры, например реализовал класс строки, какие нибудь структуры данных, класс для работы с матрицами, умный указатель и т.д.тогда следуя логики поведения этих классов он автоматом начнёт правильно перегружать операторы